# Custom Style on lightning:textarea

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, stylesheets, styleclass

I want to add custom styling to text area
  height, border, color etc

This is Component

```
<lightning:textarea name="notes" value="" class="topText" label="Notes" maxlength="300" />
```

This is css

```
.THIS.topText{
   border-color: #020202;
   height:73px;
}
```

But this is not getting applied. Class is applied to other division
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to make use of the [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) that says style the element that is a child of the element that has the class:

```
.THIS .topText textarea {
   border-color: #020202;
   height:73px;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer keith! I wish I had learnt [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) a bit earlier. It make things so simpler.